# Can you add the document edit date in the header automatically?

Tags: google-docs

After searching through the tag [google-documents](/questions/tagged/google-documents) and with this search query [[google-documents] header](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&pagesize=50&q=%5Bgoogle-documents%5D%20header) I was unable to find if it's possible to have a formula with the document's editable date and time added to the header for my documentation document so it will update automatically?

For example I would have in the header: `Last edited: 2017-01-25T10:13:12Z` updated every time an edit was made to the documentation document.